# Web socket codeignetor

Tags: php, angularjs, websocket, codeigniter-3

I am trying a simple chat application using websocket. For that i have taken the coding from https://github.com/kishor10d/CodeIgniter-Ratchet-Websocket.

But i have found the below issue:

```
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/ratchat/assets/js/angular.min.js
Source Map URL: angular.min.js.map[Learn More]
Source map error: request failed with status 404
Resource URL: http://localhost/ratchat/assets/js/angular-route.min.js
Source Map URL: angular-route.min.js.map[Learn More]
Firefox can’t establish a connection to the server at ws://192.0.53.1:8000/.(192.0.53.1:8000/.:this is my IP).
```

i had tried on terminal by giving :

```
php -q /var/www/html/chat/application/third_party/Realtime/bin/server.php
```

but not working

Any help

Answer (score 0):

First run the server.php on Your console .Then it will works. I had try it anf works fine for me